# pandas take an average of two string values in a cell

Tags: python, pandas

The below sample has some bid/ask prices. What is a good way to calculate the average (mid) in each cell for the entire df?

```
#---sample df
prices = pd.DataFrame({
    'tenor':['5Y', '10Y', '15Y', '20Y', '30Y'],
    '1M':['0.67/0.62', '1.10/1.05', '1.23/1.18', '1.38/1.33', '1.55/1.50'],
    '3M':['0.79/0.74', '1.19/1.14', '1.32/1.27', '1.49/1.44', '1.65/1.60'],
    '6M':['0.89/0.84', '1.29/1.24', '1.42/1.37', '1.60/1.55', '1.76/1.71'],
    '12M':['1.14/1.07', '1.47/1.40', '1.61/1.54', '1.80/1.72', '1.95/1.87']
    })
```

so that the below would return `0.645` , for example.

```
prices.iat[0,1]
Out[112]: '0.67/0.62'
```

Comment: How does `prices.iat[0,1]` returns 0.645?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `applymap` is nice and simple, this is unfortunately slow.

A more efficient, vectorial solution, would be to `split` and `explode` before `groupby`+`mean`:

```
(prices.set_index('tenor')
       .apply(lambda c: c.str.split('/').explode())
       .astype(float)
       .groupby(level=0, sort=False).mean()
)
```

Output:

```
          1M     3M     6M    12M
tenor                            
5Y     0.645  0.765  0.865  1.105
10Y    1.075  1.165  1.265  1.435
15Y    1.205  1.295  1.395  1.575
20Y    1.355  1.465  1.575  1.760
30Y    1.525  1.625  1.735  1.910
```

This is ~8 times faster on 50k rows

*NB. If you have many more columns than rows, you can inverse the logic to work on the other axis*

Answer (score 1):

You can split all of them on the `/` then take the mean.  Setting the non-numeric column as index first allows you to use `applymap` to do the entire rest of the df at once.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
prices = pd.DataFrame({
    'tenor':['5Y', '10Y', '15Y', '20Y', '30Y'],
    '1M':['0.67/0.62', '1.10/1.05', '1.23/1.18', '1.38/1.33', '1.55/1.50'],
    '3M':['0.79/0.74', '1.19/1.14', '1.32/1.27', '1.49/1.44', '1.65/1.60'],
    '6M':['0.89/0.84', '1.29/1.24', '1.42/1.37', '1.60/1.55', '1.76/1.71'],
    '12M':['1.14/1.07', '1.47/1.40', '1.61/1.54', '1.80/1.72', '1.95/1.87']
    })

prices = prices.set_index('tenor').applymap(lambda x: np.mean(list(map(float,x.split('/'))))).reset_index()
```

Output

```
  tenor     1M     3M     6M    12M
0    5Y  0.645  0.765  0.865  1.105
1   10Y  1.075  1.165  1.265  1.435
2   15Y  1.205  1.295  1.395  1.575
3   20Y  1.355  1.465  1.575  1.760
4   30Y  1.525  1.625  1.735  1.910
```

Answer (score 1):

For each column, you can split the string by `/` and run a lambda operation to get the mean

```
prices["1M"].str.split('/').apply(lambda x : (float(x[0])+float(x[1]))/2)

0    0.645
1    1.075
2    1.205
3    1.355
4    1.525
Name: 1M, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
x = prices.iloc[:,1:].unstack().swaplevel(1,0).str.split('/').explode().astype(float)
temp1 = x.groupby(x.index).mean().reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(x.index.drop_duplicates()))
prices.iloc[:,1:] = temp1.unstack()[prices.iloc[:,1:].columns]
```

Output:

```
  tenor     1M     3M     6M    12M
0    5Y  0.645  0.765  0.865  1.105
1   10Y  1.075  1.165  1.265  1.435
2   15Y  1.205  1.295  1.395  1.575
3   20Y  1.355  1.465  1.575   1.76
4   30Y  1.525  1.625  1.735   1.91
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, to avoid blowing up the data, which *might* help with performance:

```py
temp = prices.set_index('tenor').transform(lambda df: df.str.split('/'))
A = temp.transform(lambda df: pd.to_numeric(df.str[0])) 
B = temp.transform(lambda df: pd.to_numeric(df.str[-1]))

A.add(B).div(2)

         1M     3M     6M    12M
tenor
5Y     0.645  0.765  0.865  1.105
10Y    1.075  1.165  1.265  1.435
15Y    1.205  1.295  1.395  1.575
20Y    1.355  1.465  1.575  1.760
30Y    1.525  1.625  1.735  1.910
```

Of course, if you have more entries, then explode is a better option.

Another option, that should scale well, is to do the string work within vanilla python, before the final processing in Pandas.
We'll take advantage of Pandas' MultiIndexing to get the final output:

```py
reshaped = pd.concat({key : pd.DataFrame(string.split('/') 
                                          for string in ent)  
                       for key, ent 
                       in prices.drop(columns='tenor').items()}, 
                       axis = 1)

(reshaped
  .astype(float)
  .groupby(level=0,axis = 1, sort = False)
  .mean(1) 
  .assign(tenor = prices.tenor)
   # you can ignore the line below,
   # if column order is not important
  .loc[:, [*prices]]
)

  tenor     1M     3M     6M    12M
0    5Y  0.645  0.765  0.865  1.105
1   10Y  1.075  1.165  1.265  1.435
2   15Y  1.205  1.295  1.395  1.575
3   20Y  1.355  1.465  1.575  1.760
4   30Y  1.525  1.625  1.735  1.910
```

Again, the goal here is to try and not blow up the dataframe, and hopefully get more performance. You should get more performance by wrangling the string reshaping within Python (Pandas str methods are built on Python's string methods). As always, only tests can tell about performance.

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

```
prices.set_index('tenor').applymap(lambda x:pd.Series(x.split('/')).astype(float).mean()).reset_index()


 tenor     1M     3M     6M    12M
0    5Y  0.645  0.765  0.865  1.105
1   10Y  1.075  1.165  1.265  1.435
2   15Y  1.205  1.295  1.395  1.575
3   20Y  1.355  1.465  1.575  1.760
4   30Y  1.525  1.625  1.735  1.910
```